# Real time traffic explanation

Tags: tcp, udp

What is the difference between Best effort traffic and Real time traffic? Is TCP means best effort traffic and UDP means real time traffic? Or anything else?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, real-time traffic (voice, video, etc) does use UDP, but UDP is used for many other things, and most UDP traffic is not real-time traffic.

Classifications like "best effort" and "real time" (you can have additional classifications) are made by the network administrator to specify how the traffic is treated by the network devices--routers and switches.  An administrator decides which traffic is given priority so that network resources (bandwidth, etc) can be matched to the requirements of the traffic.

In other words, as the network administrator, it's up to you to classify traffic in ways that suits your requirements.  You decide that VoIP traffic gets priority in your network and is forwarded before other kinds of traffic.  You can also decide that Youtube videos of dancing kittens gets lower priority and limited access to your network resources.

Comment: 'Typically, real-time traffic (voice, video, etc) does use UDP'-does it mean normally we refer to UDP as real time traffic? @Ron Trunk

Comment: No. Real time traffic could be UDP, TCP, ICMP, or any other type of traffic that has been designated as real time traffic. UDP could be real time traffic, best effort, or low priority. This is about QoS and the polices that determine how traffic is handled will be different in each network.

Comment: what does the two term 'real time' and 'best effort' actually indicate? @Ron Trunk

Comment: "Real Time" doesn't have an official definition, but it generally refers to application traffic that is time sensitive.  Typically this is voice or video traffic, where excessive delays will cause the application to fail.  Other kinds of traffic, like telemetry for example, could also be considered real time.  Real time has no bearing on the traffic format at L4 or below -- as @YLearn points out, any L3 or L3 data could be considered real time.  It's based on the application.

Comment: "Best Effort" is a QoS term that means traffic is forwarded with no special prioritization.  You can consider it the "default" priority for traffic that is not classified as some other type.

Comment: So, best effort traffic refers to the traffic which we are not giving any priority and real time traffic is that one which we are giving priority. right? @Ron Trunk

Comment: The first part of that is true, but the second half (real-time) is not necessarily true (although often is in practice).  "Real time" is an application traffic type.  That doesn't define how it has to be treated.

Answer (score 0):

Real time or best effort only makes sense when you have a congested network.

When your network is congested you can mark some types of traffic as real time and some as best effort.

When a real time packet hits a switch/router it's processed first. After that the switch/router process best effort packets.

The best analogy I can give you is an avenue. The avenue here is your network. All types of cars/trucks (packets) go thorugh it.

But there are times when a firefighter truck needs to go first. And in your network you could mark firefighters as real time traffic and normal cars as best effort.

TCP can be real time and UDP could be best effort and the other way around. The answer here is the good old "it depends".

The thing is that TCP is connection oriented where UDP is not. So it's a matter of taste I guess...

Hope that helps!

Comment: what does the two term 'real time' and 'best effort' actually indicate?@rafaelbn

Comment: Indicate the class that the packet belongs. It's just another way of saying that this packet have more priority over the other... Real time = better priority. Best effort = it'll get there when it gets there...